# Meteor automatically route to https

Tags: ssl, meteor, https, dns

I just installed an SSL certificate and my https route is now working, but I'm wondering what the best way is to route all users to the https address instead of the standard www. or the naked domain?

Is there anything specific in Meteor that lets you do this, or should it be done via DNS URL forwarding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the force-ssl package on atmosphere.

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/force-ssl

*This package, part of Webapp, causes Meteor to redirect insecure connections (HTTP) to a secure URL (HTTPS). Use this package to ensure that communication to the server is always encrypted to protect users from active spoofing attacks.*